# Solr - cannot get stemming and elevation to work together

Tags: xml, solr, xsd, nutch

Solr 4.6 running on CentOS 6.5, run by a Solr newbie (me!). We use Nutch to crawl our sites, then pass the info to Solr.

Elevate was working fine until we added the stemming feature.

- Our Solr config file: [solrconfig.xml](http://www.benbrown.org/solrconfig.xml)
- Our Solr schema file: [schema.xml](http://www.benbrown.org/schema.xml)
- Our search string is:

  [solrserver]/elevate?q=[search term]&fl=content%2Ctitle%2Curl&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=content%2Ctitle&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you want elevation of documents with tokens that have been analyzed you should use the same field for both

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent">
<!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
<str name="queryFieldType">text</str>
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, will give it a try and report back ASAP.